# Draw four partition cone for plane in 2D

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I am trying to Draw a figure below where lots labels but I looks difficult.  I start with the following code but it seems not good start. Is possible to help draw the plot below:[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]

        \draw (0,0) node[dot,label=left:{$O$}] (O) {} -- (0,0,5) node[pos=1.1] (A) {$A$}; % A=z
        \draw (O) -- (4,0) node[pos=1.1] (B) {$B$}; % B=x
        \draw (O) -- (0,8) node[pos=1.1] (C) {$C$}; % C=y
        \draw (O) -- (0,-2.5) node[pos=1.1]{$D$}; 
        \draw (0.5,0,) -- ++ (0,{-0.5/sqrt(2)}) -- ++ (-0.5,0);
        \draw (2,0,) -- ++ (0,{-0.5/sqrt(2)}) -- ++ (-0.5,0);
        \path (B) -- (A) node[pos=0.3]{$\mathcal{C}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is straightforward to draw a figure that looks like your screen shot but IMHO you and all others would benefit much more if you explained what the specifics of the cone and the projection are such that one can do better.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
 % example of a path with various coordinates and nodes along the way
 \draw[-stealth] (120:4) coordinate[label=right:{$D$}](D) -- (0,0)
 coordinate[label={[anchor=-105,inner sep=4pt]:{$O$}}] (O) --
 (30:5) coordinate[label=above:{$\boldsymbol{u}$}](u) 
 node[pos=0.9,above]{$A$} ;
 % simple but admittedly also a bit lengthy way of adding an arrow
 % one could make it a style if needed
 \draw[stealth-] (30:2) node[below right]{$\widetilde{\theta}$} 
 -- ++ (120:0.5) coordinate(aux);
 \draw[dotted,thick] (aux) -- ++ (120:1.5) node[dot,label=above right:$\boldsymbol{X}$]{};
 % another example of a path with various coordinates and nodes
 % the construction is the same as above
 \draw[-stealth] (-120:4) coordinate(D') -- (O) --
    (-30:5)coordinate[label=above:{$\boldsymbol{v}$}](v) ;
 \draw[stealth-] (-30:1.5) node[above right]{$\widetilde{\theta}$} 
  -- ++ (-120:0.5) coordinate (aux);
 \draw[dotted,thick] (aux) -- ++ (-120:1.5)  node[dot,label=right:$\boldsymbol{X}$]{};
 \draw[stealth-] (O) node[anchor=25,inner sep=6pt]{$\widetilde{\theta}$} 
  -- ++ (160:0.5) coordinate (aux);
 \draw[dotted,thick] (aux) -- ++ (160:1.5)  node[dot,label=left:$\boldsymbol{X}$]{};
 \draw[stealth-] (D) ++ (-150:0.1) ++ (-60:0.5) node[left]{$-\boldsymbol{R}_2$} -- ++ (-60:1);
 \draw[stealth-] (D') ++ (150:0.1) ++ (60:0.5) node[left]{$-\boldsymbol{R}_1$} -- ++ (60:1);
 % you do not need to draw a path
 \path (u) -- (v) node [midway]{$\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{S}_1$}
 (-50:3.5) node{$\mathcal{S}_4$} (-150:3) node{$\mathcal{C}^0=\mathcal{S}_3$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Added more nodes and some very basic explanations of what is going on. If you want to understand better what is going on, it may help to look at specific node contents and see how the node is placed. In this answer, on purpose only plain Ti*k*Z is used, even though some things could be automatized more at the expense of a higher complexity. Note also that it is possible to make Ti*k*Z draw projections of some higher-dimensional shapes, i.e. if you have a mathematical description of the cone one may be able to draw it "from first principles". On the long run, if you need to produce several of such diagrams, this may pay off.

Comment: Thank you for explaining where is my mistake and that I can't use figure within standalone.  Is possible to add the label for C= S_1, S_2, C^0 = S_3, and S_4 as well please note that u and v are unit vector in the direction of cone C with sides A and the other one. Is possible to have the space between them. as in the picture. Thank you again for all the help. Sorry I have one more question what is the different between node and coordinate?

Comment: @JesZ I added them, hoping I didn't forget anything, and also added some very basic explanations. (If you can deal with 4-spheres then you may be interested in developing a more systematic approach to draw such diagrams.;-)